# Set alpha for color resource basing on another color

Tags: android, android-color

If I have `<color name="primary">#112233</color>`,

1. Can I set `android:background` attribute to `primary`, but adding opacity? For example, adding #40000000 to get `#40112233`.
2. Can I make another color, basing on primary, but adding opacity? For example, make something like `<color name="primary_semitransparent">#40000000 + @color/primary</color>` to produce `@color/primary_semitransparent` with value of `#40112233`

Answer (score 0):

This isn't an exact duplicate, but this question gets answered in [How to create a transparent Color Resource?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17768453/how-to-create-a-transparent-color-resource) pretty well.

To answer the question here as well:
If you use 8 characters for a color then the first 2 will be used for opacity. So to greate a half transparent "primary" use:
`<color name="primary">#CC112233< /color>`.